# Text input popup box

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I will like to build a popup alertview with allow the user to enter text input. I tried below code.

it works except, I need a bigger text area - like - UITextView. however, when I used UITextView with bigger Frame area. it cover the whole UIAlertView area.

Do you have any example on how to build popup text input with big text area (UITextView).

```
 UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Preset Saving..." message:@"Describe the Preset\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        UITextField *textField;
        textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        textField.delegate = self;
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
        textField.frame = CGRectMake(15, 75, 255, 30);
        textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:20];
        textField.placeholder = @"Preset Name";
        textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        textField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
        [textField becomeFirstResponder];
        [alert addSubview:textField];
```

Comment: You say potato.  I say tomato.  So you say you want to use UITextView.  But your code indicates that you use textfields instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looking into something like [CODialog](https://github.com/eaigner/CODialog). I'm not sure if it can help in your exact circumstance, hacking the details of UIAlertView is frowned upon by Apple, so will not have future-proof code.

#### [UIAlertView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. **The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.**